# Routing Error uninitialized constant controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm am trying to learn Ruby on rails and I keep getting this error.

My controller is

```
class Clasa9Controller < ApplicationController
  def multimi
  end

  def progresii
  end

  def functii
  end

  def vectori
  end

  def trigonometrie
  end

  def geometrie
  end
end
```

clasa9.html.erb

```
 <button class="btn"><%= link_to "", multimi_path %></button>
```

rails routes:

```
multimi GET    /clasa_9/multimi(.:format)           clasa_9#multimi
               progresii GET    /clasa_9/progresii(.:format)         clasa_9#progresii
                 functii GET    /clasa_9/functii(.:format)           clasa_9#functii
                 vectori GET    /clasa_9/vectori(.:format)           clasa_9#vectori
           trigonometrie GET    /clasa_9/trigonometrie(.:format)     clasa_9#trigonometrie
               geometrie GET    /clasa_9/geometrie(.:format)         clasa_9#geometrie
```

and routes.rb

```
 get 'clasa_9/multimi', to:"clasa_9#multimi", as:"multimi"

  get 'clasa_9/progresii', to:"clasa_9#progresii", as:"progresii"

  get 'clasa_9/functii', to:"clasa_9#functii", as:"functii"

  get 'clasa_9/vectori', to:"clasa_9#vectori", as:"vectori"

  get 'clasa_9/trigonometrie',  to:"clasa_9#trigonometrie", as:"trigonometrie"

  get 'clasa_9/geometrie',  to:"clasa_9#geometrie", as:"geometrie"

  devise_for :users

  get 'pages/home'

  get 'pages/clasa9'

  get 'pages/clasa10'

  get 'pages/clasa11'

  get 'pages/clasa12'

  get 'pages/about'

  root 'pages#home'
```

and im am getting

> Routing Error
>   uninitialized constant Clasa9Controller

I tried to solve this by looking up what is already posted here but I just can't solve it... I don't understand what I should change.

Comment: What is your controller file called? It must match your controller name - in your case I believe clasa9_controller.rb or clasa_9_controller.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your file is located inside the app/controllers folder, then it is probably a file name issue. Your file should have the name clasa9_controller.rb.

If not, then you should load the file by creating an initializer or by adding an autoload_path inside config/development.rb

Rails loads by default:

1. All subdirectories of app in the application and engines present at boot time. For example, app/controllers. They do not need to be the default ones, any custom directories like app/workers belong automatically to autoload_paths.
2. Any existing second level directories called app/*/concerns in the application and engines.
3. The directory test/mailers/previews.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. my controller is fine can you please tell me how to do your second solution............If not, then you should load the file by creating an initializer or by adding an autoload_path inside config/development.rb

Answer (score 0):

Look it would be `clasa9` but why that when you run this with the [`underscore`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/underscore) method like this

```
Loading development environment (Rails 5.1.4)
2.3.4 :001 > "Clasa9Controller".underscore
 => "clasa9_controller"
```

it returns `clasa9_controller` that means your controller is `clasa9` not `clasa_9` and file name will be `clasa9_controller.rb` then your `routes` would be `to: "clasa9#multimi"` like this

```
get 'clasa_9/multimi', to: "clasa9#multimi", as: "multimi"
#or
#get 'clasa_9/multimi', to: "clasa9#multimi", as: :multimi # removed doublw quotes from multimi 
...
```

Follow this it should work.